# dynamic file uploading in jsp

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp

i am trying to run this example http://www.programdiary.in/2013/02/fileuploading.html for dynamic file uploading with a preview but i keep getting this error

```
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/FileUploadAjax] threw exception [java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jsp.ajax_005ffile_jsp._jspService(ajax_005ffile_jsp.java:79)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

i have followed each steps, am i missing any library. i am not able able to figure it after many try.

this is web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>FileUploadAjax</display-name>
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>displayImage</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>displayImage</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>displayImage</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/displayImage/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>file_upload.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

and this is my directory structure
[image: Project structure]

Comment: Some good advice: Whenever you see Java code in a jsp, stay away from it. This is **really** bad practice. Second advice: debug the code or set a Java Exception breakpoint (provided your IDE supports this).

Comment: i had given breakpoint on init() method of servlet but it is not calling even that method.

Comment: The error is somewhere in `ajax_file.jsp`, so you have to set the breakpoint there.